# mysql solution for adding all users without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a pure mysql solution for the following scenario?

I want to essentially add all site users as followers to a specific defined user

The structure for the follows table is as such

```
id, user_id, other_id
```

I was able to add all users with this query, but I cannot figure out how to avoid adding follows that already exists (duplicates). 1 being the user in this case, I want all other users to follow

```
INSERT INTO follows(user_id, other_id) 
SELECT 
id,
1 as other_id 
FROM users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the rows which don't already exist......

```
INSERT INTO follows(user_id, other_id) 
SELECT id, 1 as other_id 
FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ! FROM follows WHERE user_id = users.Id and other_id = 1)
```

Comment: This is awesome, would you also know how to insert them in a random order or at least reverse?

Comment: INSERT INTO follows(user_id, other_id) 
SELECT id, 1 as other_id 
FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ! FROM follows WHERE user_id = users.Id and other_id = 1)
ORDER BY users.Id DESC

You'd have to get a little more creative for random

Comment: Oh and the ! is as typo, I meant it to be a 1.
It's just cheaper than selecting an actual column value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by making unique key constraint.. Make `user_id` as unique or combination of `user_id` and `other_id`

```
INSERT INTO follows(user_id, other_id) 
SELECT id, 1 as other_id 
FROM users ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE other_id = VALUES(other_id)
```